# WPF Control Flip

Tags: wpf, controls, flip

I've got a control that is mainly comprised of an image and a button. I want to display the image meta data on the back of the image and have the control flip horizontally when the button is pressed:

i.e.

[image]

Click the "info" button...

[image]

Rotate the image 180 degs around the axis...

[image]

Show "back" of image with meta data (or whatever really).

Obviously when the red "close" button is clicked, the image rotates around the final 180 degs so that the image is showing again.

I've not done any 3D really in XAML, but I can't see why this would be too complex...

Comment: Do you want to animate the rotation?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to be able to turn off the animation as the app will be used locally and over a remote connection. Sorry - didn't make that clear :)

Answer (score 10):

It can be done without 3D. `ScaleEffect` with changing horizontal scale from `1` to `-1` has the same visual effect:

```
<Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

You can animate `ScaleX` property to get *rotating* effect. You should also change it's Viisibility from `Visible` to `Hidden` and vice versa. To make image disappearing after rotating 90 degrees. At the same time back panel should become visible.

Comment: This only flips the image, the asker's image has a backside.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't he simulate an appearing of the backside of the image, using the same effect, but in the other way ?

Comment: I can, but I think ScaleX alone makes the rotation look very flat... Just trying to figure out what skew is needed to give it some depth :)

Answer (score 9):

A UserControl which is flippable:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.FlipControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls" Name="control">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ContentControl x:Key="BackSide" Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference control}, Path=Back}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" />
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        </ContentControl>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" ScaleX="1" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=Front}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Binding ElementName="transform" Path="ScaleX">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <local:LessThanXToTrueConverter X="0" />
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource BackSide}"/>
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace Test.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FlipControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FlipControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FrontProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Front", typeof(UIElement), typeof(FlipControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public UIElement Front
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(FrontProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FrontProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Back", typeof(UIElement), typeof(FlipControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public UIElement Back
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(BackProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FlipDurationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FlipDuration", typeof(Duration), typeof(FlipControl), new UIPropertyMetadata((Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
        public Duration FlipDuration
        {
            get { return (Duration)GetValue(FlipDurationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FlipDurationProperty, value); }
        }

        private bool _isFlipped = false;
        public bool IsFlipped
        {
            get { return _isFlipped; }
            private set
            {
                if (value != _isFlipped)
                {
                    _isFlipped = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsFlipped"));
                }
            }
        }

        private IEasingFunction EasingFunction = new SineEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };

        public FlipControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Flip()
        {
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                Duration = FlipDuration,
                EasingFunction = EasingFunction,
            };
            animation.To = IsFlipped ? 1 : -1;
            transform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animation);
            IsFlipped = !IsFlipped;
            OnFlipped(new EventArgs());
        }

        public event EventHandler Flipped;

        protected virtual void OnFlipped(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Flipped != null)
            {
                this.Flipped(this, e);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class LessThanXToTrueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public double X { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (double)value < X;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
<uc:FlipControl x:Name="fc">
    <uc:FlipControl.Front>
        <Image Source="/Images/Default.ico" />
    </uc:FlipControl.Front>
    <uc:FlipControl.Back>
        <Image Source="/Images/Error.ico" />
    </uc:FlipControl.Back>
</uc:FlipControl>
```

```
fc.Flip();
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying X-Scale transforms and while it gives an appearance of rotation, because the control doesn't skew, it seems to look quite flat. I'll continue investigating, but might well settle on this for simplicity's sake :)

Comment: I "fixed" the flipped backside problem by flipping it twice; You are right about it looking flat, but i doubt that a simple skew transform will make it look good, a perspective transform would be better.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to shear really to get the proper perspective and to do that requires 3D. I'll investigate into it further when I can justify spending more time on the UI :)

Comment: +1 for animation but on using separate controls instead of images as a UIElement, back control is not working...

Answer (score 6):

old post I know, but take a look at http://thriple.codeplex.com/

Josh smith provided a control that did this back in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

Have a [look at this project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx).

I am waiting for Silverlight's plane projections coming to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idea from this blog which shows how to do it in Silverlight. Pretty much same will work in WPF if we use ViewPort3D instead of Projection
http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/04/3d-flipper-control-using-silverlight-30.html

Comment: The interaction logic of that thing is abysmal, so while the idea might be fine i would suggest pretty much completely rewriting it.

Comment: Further are you sure you can create a RenderTransform which behaves like that?