# How to make a image swivel in wpf?

Tags: wpf, image, animation, storyboard

I was looking at [this](http://johnpapa.net/swivel-behavior-in-silverlight-3) post.

I was wondering if it was possible to make a image swivel in wpf?

If not, how would i change the solution to make my WPF image swivel repeatedly?

Comment: Seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228190/wpf-control-flip/6228730#6228730)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx) simple solution:

This is all you need.

```
<pl:Planerator Name="planerator">
        <Image Name="logo"
           Source="somePath" >
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="ScaleX" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="planerator" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"
                                             From="0" To="360"
                                             BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                             Duration="0:0:5"  
                                             AutoReverse="False"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </pl:Planerator>
```

Comment: +1, That is indeed a great solution! Never seen that one before

Comment: @Meleak It works great, especially if you want to do something like windows 8 live tiles... =)